# Retrieving Contact by PHONE.CONTENT_URI returns duplicate rows

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to retrieve phone numbers from my raw contact by account type.
Using the snippet below,

```
String SELECTION =
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='" + Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "'";

    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, SELECTION, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String type = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //String phone = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            Log.e("number",name);
           // hasPhoneNumber(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID)));
        }
        cur.close();
    }
```

I could retrieve all contact tied to the account type but, hasPhoneNumber(String contactId) returns an empty cursor.

```
private boolean hasPhoneNumber(String id) {
    Cursor pCur = this.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{id}, null);
    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(" ", "");
        if (Integer.parseInt(pCur.getString(
                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Log.e("search", "found phone number");
            pCur.close();
            return true;
        }
        pCur.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I decided to perform my query with PHONE.CONTENT_URL as:

```
String SELECTION =
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='" + Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "'";

    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, SELECTION, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String type = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phone = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            Log.e("number",phone);
           // hasPhoneNumber(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID)));
        }
        cur.close();
    }
```

This works as expected except that I have only 3 contact that matches such query on my contact list but the while loop runs for 6 times, showing each number twice. How best can I implement this and what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: This is a probably a bug but it isn't related to how you query your data. This is more of a Google-related problem. If you try and open the stock Lollipop Messenger app, you'll see duplicates rows too in the "new message" section. I'm also trying to solve this by the way

Answer (score 7):

You can try using the [REMOVE_DUPLICATE_ENTRIES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html#REMOVE_DUPLICATE_ENTRIES) parameter on the URI:

```
Uri uri = Phone.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.REMOVE_DUPLICATE_ENTRIES, "1")
        .build();
```

However, if you have two raw contacts with the same number, I don't think you can eliminate the duplicates because the above query parameter only makes Android apply `GROUP BY (RawContacts._ID, DATA1)` to the query.

Comment: ContactsContract.REMOVE_DUPLICATE_ENTRIES is added in API level 21.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I removed duplicates when querying `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`. I have an `ArrayList` holding all the contacts. Notice what I am doing with the boolean `addNewContact`. I check If I have another contact with the same `CONTACT_ID` and if I do not then it will add another contact but if it does then it will skip adding that contact. See the full snippet here:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    cur.moveToPosition(-1);
    boolean addNewContact;
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String thumb = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (allContacts==null)
                allContacts = new Vector<Contact>();


            addNewContact = true;
            for (Contact addedC:allContacts){
                if (addedC.id.equals(id))
                    addNewContact = false;
            }

            if (addNewContact) {
                Contact c = new Contact(name, id);

                if (thumb != null)
                    c.setThumb(cr, thumb);
                allContacts.add(c);
            }
        } 
    }
```

And this is my `Contact` class:

```
public class Contact {
    String name;
    Bitmap thumb;
    String id;


    public Contact(String name, String id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }



    public void setThumb(ContentResolver cr, String  uri) {

        try {
            thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, Uri.parse(uri));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (thumb!=null)
            thumb = getCroppedBitmap(thumb);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it returns you different data of multiple types, based on the mimetype.

For example, if `ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE` is `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` , you can safely fetch the phone number from there.

But if it's a different value, the field of it could mean something else, or even be null.

So, it depends on your needs. If you want to gather all information, you need to check each mimetype and fetch its data properly.